# Creating an empty page programatically

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to programatically create an empty page, let me explain what i mean.

So i created a plugin that automatically creates a new page with a simple javacript redirect function in it, this works fine.

The problem is that the page first loads the template of the site with stylesheets and javascript files before executing the javascript and this might take a long time depending on the speed of the users network.

So my question is if there is a way to create a blank page without any templates attached to it.

Or possibly a way that i can add the javascript to the header part of the page instead of the body.

The javascript is now currently being added in this way :

```
new_post = array();
    $new_post['post_title'] = $the_page_title;
    $new_post['post_name'] = $the_page_name;
    $new_post['post_content'] = "
     <script>
     // Redirect
     <script>"
```

Any help or tips on how to do this or other ways to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you have this code ? Did you try using it in `functions.php` and redirecting with `wp_redirect()`

Comment: @Sumit This code is located in my plugin php file, the redirect works just fine, the problem is that it first loads all template files before executing the javascript since this is located in the body

Comment: Yes, JavaScript redirect are not good. Hook that function on `wp` then use `wp_redirect` it will not load the page at all!

Comment: @Sumit The problem is that i have some if statements in the javascript code that evaluate where the user should be redirected to, which i can not replicate in php. So i need to use the javascript unfortunately

Comment: Then there is nothing can be done in JS (because it is loaded late) you've to change the logic in PHP to place the JS in header

Comment: @Sumit Any idea of how to do that? Cause i only know of this way to create a page programaticcaly and i can't access the header part with the 'post_content'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a post meta field to indicate this post is just a redirect when creating it:

```
$postid = wp_insert_post($newpost);
add_post_meta($postid,'redirect','1');
```

Check the post meta value and if it is a "redirect post", just output the post content (javascript redirect):

```
add_action('wp','custom_maybe_redirect');
function custom_maybe_redirect();
    global $post;
    if (!is_object($post)) {return;}
    $redirect = get_post_meta($post->ID,'redirect',true);
    if ($redirect == '1') {echo $post->post_content; exit;}
}
```

Though I agree with Sumit you should be able to anything with PHP that javascript can do, but in case you are relying on an external endpoint for the javascript (that is all I can think?) then this should do it.

Comment: ill explain why i cant use php for the redirect part : in the javascript it checks if the page is loaded through an iframe, which is not possible to check with php as far as i know.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly!,it redirects much faster now.Thank you very much.

Comment: ah ok, that makes sense. no probs ;-)